# T-SQL Extract string between two known characters

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, substring

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014.  I have a table that contains strings (assigned to field CAR) like the below:

```
ORANGE 1 FORD FIESTA;PETROL
RED 24 FORD MUSTANG; PETROL
BLACK 2 NISSAN JUKE; DIESEL
```

However, I need to extract everything from the 2nd space ' ' to the first semi colon ; to look like the below:

```
FORD FIESTA
FORD MUSTANG
NISSAN JUKE
```

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAR, CHARINDEX(' ', CAR) , CHARINDEX(';',CAR) - CHARINDEX(' ', CAR) + Len(';'))
FROM tblStock;
```

However, this gives me the below:

```
 1 FORD FIESTA;
24 FORD MUSTANG;
2 NISSAN JUKE;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should clean up the data *before* storing it in the database. SQL in general and T-SQL in particular are *very* weak when it comes to text processing. Data that's used in querying, filtering should be stored in separate columns. If you have data that's only occasionally used you could store it as JSON or XML and use eg JSON_VALUE to extract specific fields

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos appreciate what you are saying but this is from a 3rd party system that I have no control over and can only perform read-only selects from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Car] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('ORANGE 1 FORD FIESTA;PETROL')
,('RED 24 FORD MUSTANG; PETROL')
,('BLACK 2 NISSAN JUKE; DIESEL')
 
Select A.*
      ,NewValue = stuff(left(Car,charindex(';',Car+';')-1),1,patindex('%[0-9] %',Car+'0'),'')
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
Car                            NewValue
ORANGE 1 FORD FIESTA;PETROL    FORD FIESTA
RED 24 FORD MUSTANG; PETROL    FORD MUSTANG
BLACK 2 NISSAN JUKE; DIESEL    NISSAN JUKE
```

Comment: nice use of stuff to fill with nothing before "any number followed by a space".

Comment: @sacse Thanks for the grin  :)

Comment: Thank you, I have gone with your solution

Answer (score 1):

You are picking everything from first space to the first semicolon.

You can pick in the reversed string from the "first semicolon" to first "space followed by a number" (assuming every record has the number in it) and then finally reverse the string returned.

```
SELECT reverse(trim(substring(reverse(car), charindex(';', reverse(car), 1)+1, 
                 PATINDEX('% [0-9]%', REVERSE(car)) - charindex(';', reverse(car), 1)))) Final
```

Please find the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d20b76b2ca8efcf243dfa73815cfe96).

Comment: Thank you but TRIM is not present out of the box in SQL Server 2014

Comment: @Michael You can replace that with LTRIM, RTRIM.